# Troubleshooting ethernet->fiber->ethernet with media converters

Tags: switch, fiber, media-conversion

I'm trying to get the following setup to work:

ethernet switch <---> media converter <---> fiber cable <---> media converter <---> ethernet switch

The switches are identical tp-link managed gigabit switches; the fiber cable is multimode om2 with LC connectors; and I'm using identical 10GTek media converters.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting. Here's what the setup looks like:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by doing a loop-back test to see if each MediaTek and SFP can connect to itself.  Use a fresh fiber patch cord.  The one pictured may have been bent and twisted so much that it could be damaged.

Comment: What's the SFP module type?

Comment: Try different cables - the fiber patch may have been overbent and the black TP looks damaged or badly DIY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't bend fiber like that, it's sensitive.
- The black patch cable might be damaged, replace.
- Check the SFP modules - for gigabit over MMF you'll need 1000BASE-SX (850 nm).
- Verify SFP compatibility with the converters - quite a few vendors force you to use their branded modules.
- You can check a fiber port with a simplex cable as loopback.
- One converter shows 1000M, the other 100M - if they're not of the switching kind that won't work.

Comment: Thank you! There were two problems - one faulty ethernet cable and the fibre cable was broken too. I replaced those and it worked fine. Weird, because they were both new from the manufacturers.